# sampling a multimensional posterior distribution using MCMC Metropolis-Hastings algo in R

Tags: r, statistics, bayesian, sampling, mcmc

I am quite new in sampling posterior distributions(so therefore Bayesian approach) using a MCMC technique based on Metropolis-Hastings algorithm.
I am using the mcmc library in R for this. My distribution is multidimensionnal. In order to check if this metro algorithm works for multivaiate distribution I did it successfully on a multidimensional student-t distribution (package mvtnorm, function dmvt).
Now I want to apply the same thing to my multivariate distribution (2 vars x and y) but it doesn't work; I get an error : Error in X[, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions

Here is my code:

```
library(mcmc)
library(mvtnorm)
my.seed <- 123

logprior<-function(X,...)
{
      ifelse( (-50.0 <= X[,1] & X[,1]<=50.0) & (-50.0 <= X[,2] & X[,2]<=50.0), return(0), return(-Inf))
}

logpost<-function(X,...)
{
      log.like <- log( exp(-((X[,1]^2 + X[,2]^2 - 4)/10 )^2) * sin(4*atan(X[,2]/X[,1])) )
      log.prior<-logprior(X)
      log.post<-log.like + log.prior # if flat prior, the posterior distribution is the likelihood one
      return (log.post)
}

x <- seq(-5,5,0.15)
y <- seq(-5,5,0.15)
X<-cbind(x,y)

#out <- metrop(function(X) dmvt(X, df=3, log=TRUE), 0, blen=100, nbatch=100) ; this works
out <- metrop(function(X) logpost(X), c(0,0), blen=100, nbatch=100)
out <- metrop(out)
out$accept
```

So I tried to respect the same kind of format than for the MWE, but it doesn't work still as I got the error mentioned before. 
Another thing, is that applying logpost to X works perfectly.

Thanks in advance for your help, best

Answer (score 0):

The `metrop` function passes individual samples, and therefore a simple vector to `logpost`, not a matrix (which is what `X` is). Hence, the solution is to change `X[,1]` and `X[,2]` to `X[1]` and `X[2]`, respectively.

I ran it like this, and it leads to other issues (`X[2]/X[1]` is NaN for the initialization), but that has more to do with your specific likelihood model and is out of the scope of your question.